# Javascript JQuery - dynamic button creation with events with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I'm trying to create and append buttons to a page in html with events assigned to them, this way:

```
var mdata = JSON.parse(data);
mdata.forEach(function(k) {
    $("#routesPage").append("<button class='accordion' onclick='setRoute("+k._id.$id+")'>"+k.nombre+"</button>");
        routesArray[k._id.$id]=k;
    });
```

Previously I'm making a call to a PHP service that gives me the data from a MongoDB database, and for each data I want to create a button with an assigned variable and call to setRoute(). k._id.$id is a string, which is correctly formatted. And I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I'm unable to figure out the problem. Is there any way to fix this or do it in a more efficient way?

UPDATE: This is the raw data that I recieve from the DB.

```
[{"_id":{"$id":"58f224ec34189e19cce416d9"},
"origin":"Chicago, IL",
"destination":"Los Angeles, CA",
"waypoints":[
    {"location":"Joplin, MO","stopover":false},
    {"location":"Oklahoma City, OK","stopover":true}],
"provideRouteAlternatives":false,"travelMode":"WALKING",
"unitSystem":"google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC",
"nombre":"Ruta de Chicago a Los Angeles"}, ...
```

Comment: what's the $id variable

Comment: It's an inside variable of a MongoDB document: it's a mandatory field that contains an unique id for each document. It's inside an object called _id so the way to access it is like that.

Comment: Provide us raw `data` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No errors. Maybe problem is somewhere else? Are you getting data using PHP and Ajax?

```js
var routesArray = Array();
var mdata = JSON.parse('[{"_id":{"$id":"58f224ec34189e19cce416d9"},"origin":"Chicag‌​o, IL","destination":"Los Angeles, CA","waypoints":[{"location":"Joplin, MO","stopover":false},{"location":"Oklahoma City, OK","stopover":true}],"provideRouteAlternatives":false,"trav‌​elMode":"WALKING","u‌​nitSystem":"google.m‌​aps.UnitSystem.METRI‌​C","nombre":"Ruta de Chicago a Los Angeles"}]');
mdata.forEach(function(k) {
  $("#routesPage").append("<button class='accordion' onclick='setRoute(\"" + k._id.$id + "\")'>" + k.nombre + "</button>");
  routesArray[k._id.$id] = k;
});

function setRoute(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="routesPage"></div>
```

## Edit

Change
`onclick='setRoute(" + k._id.$id + ")'` to `onclick='setRoute(\"" + k._id.$id + "\")'` and check if works.

Comment: The data is being recieved correctly via a $.post() call. The problem is passing the variable. If I make the call to setRoute() without parameters, it works.

Comment: So the problem was in escaping the variables, I supposed it was something of that sort, but I could not figure it out exactly how it was. Thank you!